# 3D visualization - rotating cube

Tags: graphics, visualization, data-visualization

I have many 3D vectors. I want to plot them in a cube so that each dimension is on a particular side of the cube.

Now, I am looking for some visualization/tool or library that lets me rotate this cube in 3D and see the vectors in various different angles.

Thanks
Abhishek S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Processing](http://processing.org/), it is somewhat intended for data visualization and in addition to simple control over 3D drawing, it also has the full power of Java programming language. You can see numerous works, done by other people on [OpenProcessing](http://www.openprocessing.org/).

However, if you are into anything serious, I would suggest you to use some ohter IDE than the default one. I use Eclipse for that, importing Processing as a library into my project. It requires a tiny boilerplate to work, but then you're happy!